# Choose between Yii 1, Yii 2 and latest Yii Gihub commit for a new project

Tags: php, yii, yii2

We are about to start a new project and we want to use Yii for it. After reading Yii website, I found out that the release date for Yii 2 beta has been set to early 2014 and judging by github, that milestone is 94% ready.

What is our best bet in this case when choosing Yii version? If we go with stable Yii 1, is it going to be easy to later update that code to Yii 2.0 or is it going to be a complete rewrite or some bad hack? Or if we go with Yii 2.0 alpha, will it be relatively easy to update then? The instability of alpha is ok, we anyway will likely be working on basic things such as authentication, registration, etc by the time beta is released? And finally is using the latest github commit (which is a 94% complete beta) a good idea or is it in a semi-functional "development" state and might not work at all?

Also how compatible are the Yii extensions? If we go with Yii 2, are we going to be limited to a relatively small selection of Yii 2 extensions?

Comment: if you look at http://www.yiiframework.com/news/76/yii-2-0-alpha-is-released, it says that yii2 is a complete rewrite of yii. So that means that something basic has changed in this release. So if you are thinking to start with yii and then move to yii2, then it will be not a good idea. If you think you start developing using yii2 then it is also not a good idea because yii official website itself says that dont use it for development purposes. That means there could be bugs not typically related authentication. There may be some basic instabilities in this release.

Comment: Why is this put on hold? This is an absolutely valid and well worded question, I'll also add an answer.

Comment: Since the question is on hold, I add a short answer as a comment.

First of all, Yii 2 is **not** backward-compatibile with Yii 1. This also applies to extensions. In my opinion the API of Yii 2.0 is already pretty stable now. It may occur that you have to change minor things, but from my experience with Yii this chance is pretty small and I am almost sure that this will be feasible. But, there are not as many extensions available for Yii 1 than for Yii 2. Nevertheless, I'd say go with Yii 2.

Comment: Addon: I recommend an installation with composer of the latest master and committing your `composer.lock` file to ensure a consistent state of the framework and extensions.

Comment: If your project is not a simple application, it will be a failure if you'll choose the first yii. It is: 1. no namespaces, 2. no dependency manager, 3. much slower, 4. soon will not be supported, especially extensions. Yii 2 is enough stable already, for starting developing.

Comment: My experiance with Yii2 for internal project:
You can't upgrade yii1 with yii2 letter,
but you can  easy updating yii2-beta to yii2-alpha when ready.
Registration and user management is already implemented in the base template of yii2, your major task in the beginning will be to figure out how all works .. to properly install and setup the project and understand the new model/query principles, you definitely need a good Software Architect to play with it for few days before any production work can be done.
Widget support is very poor for now, be prepared to write your own or hack them with JS.

Comment: I would just use Ruby on Rails. Rails is miles ahead of Yii2. There are so many details that Yii has to fix, like accessing helpers with HAML, turning forms into links, etc. Some things just can't be done because PHP doesn't have Ruby's features, so you have to add more verbose code or functions to simulate what Ruby would do.